# Getting an empty string when trying to decode AES-128-CBC ciphertext

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs

Even though I'm sure I have the right data (verified through an online decoder), I'm only getting empty strings as my output from the decoder.

This is my javascript:

```
var cipher  = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data.split("--")[0]);
var inv     = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data.split("--")[1]);

console.log("Ciphertext");
console.log(cipher);                             // as word array
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(cipher)); // as hex string
console.log("IV");
console.log(inv);                                // as word array
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(inv));    // as hex string

// don't worry, this key won't be used in production ;-)
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("GzUaLsk7SI9VDja3");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, key, { iv: inv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });

console.log(decrypted);

decrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(decrypted);
```

`data` is a string with the ciphertext and IV, both Base64 encoded, separated by 2 dashes ('--').

I pasted the hex representation of the ciphertext and IV into [this tool](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/) to verify whether my data is right, and that gave me the desired result.

Can someone please help me with why I'm getting empty strings (and empty word arrays, for that matter) out of the decrypt function? I do not get any errors with this code at all, by the way.

Comment: The most logical reason would be that the plaintext is empty. In that case you get a single block of ciphertext which just contains padding. PKCS#7 padding is *always* applied. Try with `CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding` and show us the "hexified" decryption result...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The plaintext obviously isn't supposed to be empty. The output currently is an empty Wordlist, so I see no point in showing the hex form ;-)

Comment: Question: Is there a specific reason why there is an open bounty if your question is answered ?

Comment: Yes: nobody answered the question other than myself and I cannot award myself the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I expected, the problem wasn't the padding. Here is the working code:

```
var cipher = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data.split("--")[0]);
var inv    = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data.split("--")[1]);

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("GzUaLsk7SI9VDja3");
var aesDecryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createDecryptor(key, { iv: inv });

var decrypted = aesDecryptor.process(cipher);
var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: Lifesaver! Only thing you missed is the "finalize" call on aesDecryptor. If you don't call finalize, you will lose the last block of crypto. I'm putting an edit in to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Please consider upvoting my answer if my answer helped you ;-)

Comment: Already done. TBH, I can't believe this doesn't have more upvotes, because without this, I'd probably still be stuck on this issue.